# Is this an acceptable way to make threaded SQLAlchemy queries from Twisted?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, twisted, python-multithreading

I've been doing some reading on using SQLAlchemy's ORM in the context of a Twisted application.  It's a lot of information to digest, so I'm having a bit of trouble putting all the pieces together.  So far, I've gathered the following absolute truths:

1. One session implies one thread.  Always.
2. `scoped_session`, by default, provides us with a way of constraining sessions to a given thread.  In other words, I am sure that by using `scoped_session`, I will not pass sessions to other threads (unless I do so explicitly, which I won't).

I also gathered that there are some issues relating to lazy/eager-loading and that one possible approach is to dissociate ORM objects from a session and reattach them to another session when changing threads.  I'm quite fuzzy on the details, but I also concluded that `scoped_session` renders many of these points moot.

**My *first* question is whether or not I am severely mistaken in my above conclusions**.

Beyond that, I've crafted this approach, which I hope is satisfactory.

I begin by creating a `scoped_session` object...

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=_my_engine))
```

... which I will then use from a context manager, in order to handle exceptions and clean-up gracefully:

```
@contextmanager
def transaction_context():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.remove()  # dispose of the session
```

Now all I need to do is to use the above context manager in a function that is deferred to a separate thread.  I've thrown together a decorator to make things a bit prettier:

```
def threaded(fn):
    @wraps(fn)  # functools.wraps
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return deferToThread(fn, *args, **kwargs)  # t.i.threads.deferToThread
    return wrapper
```

Here is an example of how I intend to use the whole shebang.  Below is a function that performs a DB lookup using the SQLAlchemy ORM:

```
@threaded
def get_some_attributes(group):
    with transaction_context() as session:
        return session.query(Attribute).filter(Attribute.group == group)
```

**My *second* question is whether or not this approach is viable.**

- Am I making any fundamentally flawed assumptions?
- Are there any caveats?
- Is there a better way?

**Edit:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078696/why-is-my-scoped-session-raising-an-attributeerror-session-object-has-no-attr) is a related question concerning the unexpected error in my context manager.

Comment: Well, I guess the foremost question that everyone will have is:  does it work the way that you coded it?

Comment: @bitcycle, Incidentally (and surprisingly), no... it doesn't work.  I'm getting a `AttributeError` in my context manager -- apparently `Session` has no attribute `remove`.  This is rather surprising -- a

Comment: This looks mostly right (except it should be `Session.remove()`).  One thing to keep in mind is that some database drivers, such as `sqlite3`, don't allow their connections to be passed between threads.  I'm fairly sure `scoped_session` objects handle this appropriately (it's been a while since I used SQLAlchemy).

Comment: @markrwilliams, Great, thank you!  Just to be clear -- I do **not** need to concern myself with eager-loading if I use this approach?

Comment: It might be useful to just use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alchimia - I'm not 100% sure they're doing it right either, but at least that would make only one place to get the logic right instead of replicating it in every application :)

Comment: As @Glyph mentioned, [Alchimia](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alchimia) already does some of this. It works for the most part (although it's still fairly incomplete) but it doesn't yet have the thread-pinning necessary to make sqlite and friends happy. Contributions are welcome and it's probably a better starting point than doing it from scratch.

Comment: @Glyph, Thanks for the suggestion!  Acording to Alchimia's docs, this does not allow you to use the ORM -- or am I missing something?

Comment: I am pretty sure Alchimia does not wrap the ORM.  (Perhaps "yet", perhaps few people actually like the ORM?)

Comment: And yes, @jerith, implementing thread-pinning to make SQLite and others (Oracle, I believe) happy, would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Right now I work on this exact problem, and I think I found a solution.

Indeed, you must defer all database access functions to a thread. But in your solution, you remove the session after querying the database, so all your results ORM objects will be detached and you wont have access to their fields.

You can't use scoped_session because in Twisted we have only one MainThread (except with things that work in deferToThread). We can, however, use `scoped_sesssion` with `scopefunc`.

In Twisted there is a great thing known as `ContextTracker`:

> provides a way to pass arbitrary key/value data up and down a call
>   stack without passing them as parameters to the functions on that call
>   stack.

In my twisted web app in method `render_GET` I set a `uuid` parameter:

```
call = context.call({"uuid": str(uuid.uuid4())}, self._render, request)
```

and then I call the `_render` method to do the actual work (work with db, render html, etc).

I create the `scoped_session` like this:

```
scopefunc = functools.partial(context.get, "uuid")
Session = scoped_session(session_factory, scopefunc=scopefunc)
```

Now within any function calls of `_render` I can get session with:

```
Session()
```

and at the end of `_render` I have to do `Session.remove()` to remove the session.

It worksa with my webapp and I think can work for other tasks.

This is completely standalone example, show how all it work together.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site, NOT_DONE_YET
from twisted.python import context
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import uuid
import functools

engine = create_engine(
    'sqlite:///test.sql',
    connect_args={'check_same_thread': False},
    echo=False)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
scopefunc = functools.partial(context.get, "uuid")
Session = scoped_session(session_factory, scopefunc=scopefunc)
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


class TestPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        context.call({"uuid": str(uuid.uuid4())}, self._render, request)
        return NOT_DONE_YET

    def render_POST(self, request):
        return self.render_GET(request)

    def work_with_db(self):
        user = User(name="TestUser")
        Session.add(user)
        Session.commit()
        return user

    def _render(self, request):
        print "session: ", id(Session())
        d = threads.deferToThread(self.work_with_db)

        def success(result):
            html = "added user with name - %s" % result.name
            request.write(html.encode('UTF-8'))
            request.finish()
            Session.remove()
        call = functools.partial(context.call, {"uuid": scopefunc()}, success)
        d.addBoth(call)
        return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reactor.listenTCP(8888, Site(TestPage()))
    reactor.run()
```

I print out id of session, and you can see that its different for each request. If you remove `scopefunc` from `scoped_session` constructor and do two simultaneous request(insert time.sleep to `work_with_db`), you will get one common session for this two requests.

> The scoped_session object by default uses threading.local() as storage, so that a single Session is maintained for all who call upon the scoped_session registry, but only within the scope of a single thread

a problem here that in twisted we have only one thread for all requests. Thats why we have to create own `scopefunc`, that will show the difference between requests.

An other problem, that twisted didnt pass context to callbacks and we have to wrap callback and send current context to it.

```
call = functools.partial(context.call, {"uuid": scopefunc()}, success)
```

Still I dont know how to make it work with `defer.inLineCallback`, that I use everywhere in my code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Would you mind posting a more detailed example that explicitly shows how `ContextTracker`, `_render` and `scoped_session` all fit together?  I'm having trouble seeing the big picture.  Why is the `scopefunc` necessary with the `scoped_session`?  Thank you!

Comment: @blz add example and explanation of scopefunc using.

Comment: @aborilov Thanks! Nice solution you got here... I wonder if this could be done a bit more implicitly with a decorator