# Why is my scoped_session raising an AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up a system that elegantly defers database operations to a seperate thread in order to avoid blocking during Twisted callbacks.

So far, here is my approach:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThread

_engine = create_engine(initialization_string)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=_engine))


@contextmanager
def transaction_context():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        # No need to do session.rollback().  session.remove will do it.
        raise
    finally:
        session.remove()


def threaded(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return deferToThread(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This should allow me to wrap a function with the `threaded` decorator and then use the `transaction_context` context manager in said function's body.  Below is an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from my_lib.orm import User, transaction_context, threaded
from twisted.internet import reactor


@threaded
def get_n_users(n):
    with transaction_context() as session:
        return session.query(User).limit(n).all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_n_users(n).addBoth(len)
    reactor.run()
```

However, when I run the above script, I get a failure containing the following traceback:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 781, in __bootstrap
    self.__bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 191, in _worker
    result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "testaccess.py", line 9, in get_n_users
    return session.query(User).limit(n).all()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/louis/Documents/Python/knacki/knacki/db.py", line 36, in transaction_context
    session.remove()
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I was not expecting this at all.  What am I missing?  Did I not instantiate my `scoped_session` properly?

**Edit:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076105/is-this-an-acceptable-way-to-make-threaded-sqlalchemy-queries-from-twisted) is a related question about integrating this setup with Twisted.  It might help clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Short answer**

Call `.remove()` on `Session`, not `session`.

**Long answer**:

`scoped_session` doesn't really return a `Session` class.  Instead, it creates an object that pays attention to which thread it's called in.  Calling it will either return the existing `Session` instance associated with that thread or associate a new one and return that.  A [thread local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) is what associates a thread with a session.

The `remove` method on a `scoped_session` object removes the session object currently associated with the thread in which it's called.  That means it's the opposite of `scoped_session.__call__`, which is kind of a confusing API.

Here's a short Python script to illustrate the behavior.

```
import threading
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(_engine))


def scoped_session_demo(remove=False):
    ids = []

    def push_ids():
        thread_name = threading.currentThread().getName()
        data = [thread_name]

        data.append(Session())
        if remove:
            Session.remove()
        data.append(Session())

        ids.append(data)

    t = threading.Thread(target=push_ids)
    t.start()
    t.join()

    push_ids()

    sub_thread, main_thread = ids

    sub_name, sub_session_a, sub_session_b = sub_thread
    main_name, main_session_a, main_session_b = main_thread

    print sub_name, sub_session_a == sub_session_b
    print main_name, main_session_a == main_session_b
    print sub_name, '==', main_name, sub_session_a == main_session_b


print 'Without remove:'
scoped_session_demo()
print 'With remove:'
scoped_session_demo(True)
```

Its output:

```
Without remove:
Thread-1 True
MainThread True
Thread-1 == MainThread False
With remove:

Thread-2 False
MainThread False
Thread-2 == MainThread False
```

Comment: @markwilliams, It works!  Accepted!  Thank you so much!  Do I need to concern myself with eager loading if I employ this approach?

Comment: I got the same error and I stumbled upon this post. In the documentation, it explicitly mentions to use 'scoped_session.remove()', and later on it says Session.remove(). It is pretty confusing which one to use. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html