# Multiprocessing and SQLAlchemy Error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

We are building a software that reads thousands of XML files and imports their content into a SQLite database using SQLAlchemy.

Please find below the relevant parts of our code:

**File 1:**

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
...
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith("-endpoint.xml"):
        xmls.append([self.database, os.path.join(path, file), self.debug])

pool = ThreadPool(threads)
try:
    def multi_run_wrapper(args):
        return collectors.import_asset(*args)

    results = pool.map(multi_run_wrapper, xmls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
except:
    if self.debug:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

**File 2, part 1:**

```
def import_asset(db, xml, debug = False):
    tree = ET.parse(xml)
    root = tree.getroot()
    signcheck = root.find('Signcheck')
    usersArray = []
    running_processes = []
    autoruns = []

    machine_id = add_machine(root, xml, db, debug)
```

**File 2, part 2:**

```
def add_machine(root, file_path, db, debug = False):
    ...
    machine = Machine(hostname=hostname, operating_system=operating_system, version=Version)
    db.add(machine)
    db.commit()
```

**File 3:**

Throughout the code, 'db' is whatever the return value of this function is:

```
def open(sqlite_db_path = None):
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + sqlite_db_path)
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    return scoped_session(session())
```

**Error Message:**

```
TypeError: 'Session' object is not callable
```

We have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078696/why-is-my-scoped-session-raising-an-attributeerror-session-object-has-no-attr) that scoped_session() does not return a true Session() object. But we have not been able to use that information to fix our code.

Thank you in advance for your kind assistance with this hurdle.

Comment: Why would you call `scoped_session(session())` ? rather than passing the object as `scoped_session(session)` ? Clearly the error says, session object created using sessionmaker() is not callable.

Comment: `scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))`, pass the session factory created by sessionmaker as is instead of a `Session` created by the factory (the call).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the session factory `session`, when you should be calling the `scoped_session` instead (see [Contextual/Thread-local Sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions)).

So it should be

```
scoped_session(session)()
```

instead of

```
scoped_session(session())
```

In order to avoid confusion, I would recommend to rename `session` to `session_factory`. So something like this should work:

```
def open(sqlite_db_path = None):
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + sqlite_db_path)
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    return scoped_session(session_factory)()
```

Answer (score 3):

The fix for this was simply to replace this:

```
def open(sqlite_db_path = None):
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + sqlite_db_path)
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    return scoped_session(session())
```

With this:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + sqlite_db_path)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
return scoped_session(session_factory)
```

Thanks to all the people that responded to this thread.